# Android Google Map search Location along route

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-3

I want to search and display result based on google transits route.

> The scenario is basically if **user x** is traveling from location **A to E** and a **user z** is traveling from location **F to P.**
>
> If a user **Y** is on **location C somewhere in between to A and E**, want to join for some user
>   **whose is passing and starting point of same to his location "C"**. So S/he
>   can search the search result should **show details of X not z**.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After Lots of research finally found a library which could help in chacking the Place which lies between a route. Please checkout the below link.

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/
```